# Timeout while reading csv file from url in R

Tags: r, csv, timeout

I currently have a script in R that loops around 2000 times (`for` loop), and on each loop it queries data from a database using a url link and the `read.csv` function to put the data into a variable.

My problem is: when I query low amounts of data (around 10000 rows) it takes around 12 seconds per loop and its fine. But now I need to query around 50000 rows of data per loop and the query time increases quite a lot, to 50 seconds or so per loop. And this is fine for me but sometimes I notice it takes longer for the server to send the data (≈75-90 seconds) and APPARENTLY the connection times out and I get these errors:

> Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
>
> In addition: Warning message:
>
> In file(file, "rt") : cannot open: HTTP status was '0 (nil)'

or this one:

> Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
>
> In addition: Warning message:
>
> In file(file, "rt") : InternetOpenUrl failed: 'The operation timed
>   out'

I don't get the same warning every time, it changes between those two.

Now, what I want is to avoid my program to stop when this happens, or to simply prevent this timeout error and tell R to wait more time for the data. I have tried these settings at the start of my script as a possible solution but it keeps happening.

```
options(timeout=190)
setInternet2(use=NA)
setInternet2(use=FALSE)
setInternet2(use=NA)
```

Any other suggestions or workarounds? Maybe to skip to the next loop when this happens and store in a variable the loop number of the times this error occurred so it can be queried again in the end but only for those `i`'s in the loop that were skipped due to the connection error? The ideal solution would be, of course, to avoid having this error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution using the `RCurl` package:

You can change the `timeout` option using

```
curlSetOpt(timeout = 200)
```

or by passing it into the call to `getURL`

```
getURL(url_vect[i], timeout = 200)
```

---

A solution using base R:

Simply download each file using `download.file`, and then worry about manipulating those file later.

Comment: For the first solution, I could not find the function curlSetOpt(), I assume this belongs to an extra package which I dont use. And for the second solution, I use read.csv directly with the link as 'file' and this function does not have a timeout option.

Comment: Those functions are from `RCurl`.  I read Laszlo's solution and thought you were using that package.

Comment: As a matter of good practice, it is best to separate downloading files from using them.  (That way, if your processing causes an error, you don't have to re-download the file and use up bandwidth.)  Have one loop calling (only) `download.file` and another calling `read.csv`.

Comment: So, I used download.file as you suggested, and combined with the options(timeout=190) I had before it seemed to work, did a full 2150 loops that lasted 25 hours and no timeouts or any errors. You might want to edit your answer so I can accept the download.file usage as chosen solution. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I see this is an older post, but it still comes up early in the list of Google results, so...

If you are downloading via WinInet (rather than curl, internal, wget, etc.) options, including timeout, are inherited from the system.  Thus, you cannot set the timeout in R. You must change the Internet Explorer settings.  See Microsoft references for details:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/181050
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/193625

Answer (score 0):

This is partial code that I show you, but you can modify to you're needs :

```
        # connect to website
        withRestarts(
            tryCatch(
                webpage <- getURL(url_vect[i]),
                finally = print(" Succes.")
            ), 
            abort = function(){},
            error = function(e) {
                       i<-i+1
            }
        )
```

In my case the **url_vect[i]** was one of the url's I copied information. This will increase the time you need to wait for the program to finish sadly.

**UPDATED**

[tryCatch how to example](http://mazamascience.com/WorkingWithData/?p=912)

Comment: So, this would skip the error and continue with the following loop? No way to avoid the error in the first place?

Comment: This option retries every time, if it gets an error it just skips it.

Comment: I believe this is an R internet configuration problem, there must be some option or setting that is causing this... Because I have translated the same code to Matlab and in Matlab I never get an error when doing those long queries and loops.. I appreciate the solution anyway and will use it if no optimal (avoid the error) solution is found.

Comment: You can be right, I used my solution for getting information from websites and it worked out. In my case I could not do a lot of requests in a sort time because of the server.